# How to change a specific parameters of the specific elements in an array-list based on another elements parameters

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to java but have been playing with array-lists and am now stuck.

I have an array list created off a class called Car with three parameters one of which is called **times moved**.

ArrayList:

```
 private ArrayList<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>() ;
```

Car class

```
 public Car ( String licenseNum, String carStatus , int timesMoved)
 {   
  licensePlate = licenseNum ;
  status = carStatus ;
  moved = timesMoved;
 }
```

I am reading input of a file that is supposed to be like a garage and says if a car is **"Arriving"** or **"Departing"**

I am trying to write a code using an if statement that says if the status is "Departing" then the current element gets deleted the all elements in front of it add one to their **"times moved parameter"**

The part I am stuck on is the one where, based on the element getting deleted, all the elements in front of it in the array list add one to their **"times moved"** parameter.

Would anyone give me some advice on how it would be possible to do that?

I came up with this but it does not seem to work

```
public void carDepart()
   {
     for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++ )
        {
         Car current = list.get( i ) ;   // get next car
            if (current.getStatus().equals("DEPART"))
            {
              int pos = list.indexOf(i);

                for ( int j = 0 ; pos < j ; j++)
                {
                 current.setTimesMoved(1 + current.getTimesMoved());
                }

                 list.remove(i);
          }
          break;
       }  
    }
```

Second method

```
    public void moveCarInGarage()
    {
      for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++ )
    {
       Car current = list.get( i ) ;     // get next car
       if (current.getStatus().equals("ARRIVE"))
     {
         currentCars++;

       if (currentCars <= 10) 
       {
           System.out.println("Car with license plate" + 
            current.getLicenseNum() + " has been moved into the garage");
       }
       else 
       {
           System.out.println("The garage is full at this " +
           "time so come back later");
       }
   }
     else 
     {
         currentCars--;
         System.out.println("Car with license plate" + 
           current.getLicenseNum() + " is departing and has been moved " 
                 + current.getTimesMoved() + " times" );
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: How about 1. finding the index of the car you're going to delete, then 2. looping over cars between that index and `list.size()-1` (or `zero`, depending on the direction), then calling `setTimesMoved` on each car in the range?

Comment: How would you call it on each car in the range?

Comment: `list.get(i).setTimesMoves(1 + list.get(i).getTimesMoved)`. I will be more readable if you use a for-each loop on a sublist (`for(Car car: list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)) {car.setTimesMoved(1 + car.getTimesMoved())}`).

Comment: I'm not sure if you know this already, but you can use the same parameter names in your constructor as your attributes if you do, `this.attributeName = attributeName;`. In my opinion, this is a bit more elegant.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have mentioned the break statement. That threw you off. Put a return statement right after your `list.remove(i)` statement. A break statement will only stop both loops if it's in the outer loop. Obviously, this makes it difficult to run your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do. In it, I assume you are using getters and setters. You can also call the attributes directly assuming you've set the access modifiers in a way that allows you to do so.

All I did was create a new method called incrementTimesMoved() that iterates through your ArrayList and increments all the "moved" attributes in it's elements until it gets to the one with a given index. It removes this, and stops running.

```
public class MCVE {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   // IMO list isn't very descriptive, so I changed it to carList.
   ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();

   // Add a bunch of values to carList here.

   for(int i = 0; i < carList.size(); i++) {
      if(carList.get(i).getStatus().equals("Departing")) {
         incrementTimesMoved(i, carList);
         return; // stops the method
      }
   }

}

// only static because I am calling in the main() function
private static void incrementTimesMoved(int index, ArrayList<Car> carList) {

   for(int i = 0; i < carList.size(); i++) {

      if(i == index) {
         carList.remove(index);
         return;
      }

      carList.get(i).setMoved(carList.get(i).getMoved() += 1);
   }
}

}
```

Comment: I did not 100% understand what you did but picked answer because of effort. Anyway can you please see what I did and if there is anyway it could work? Logically it made sense to me

Comment: @Arthur The issue is that your return statement executes the first time the loop runs, and that you never remove the Car object that has the "Depart" status attribute.

Comment: I just had a remove.list(i); and it still did not work. Let me try removing the return. Now it runs and never stops lol. I mean is the logic correct like is there a way to make that kind of loop execution work or is it totally wrong?

Comment: @Arthur It's `list.remove(<index>)` not `remove.list(<index>)` You need a return or a break statement to stop the loop from executing when you don't want it to. Think about where to place it. You are 99% of the way there.

Comment: Updated the code slightly. It runs now but still does not increment. I also added my 2nd method

Comment: @Arthur You're still making the same mistake. Think about it. When do you want the loop to stop? Just after you've found the Car object with "Depart" status, incremented everything  you need to, and removed that car, right? So where do you put the return statement? Because right now, it just checks the if-statement, discovers it's false, and moves on down to the break statement.

Comment: I added the return statement right after the list.remove but it still says 0 for when i print in the 2nd method. Any reason why?